# MapReduce Vowel Cont

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am looking to change my MapReduce code that finds words in a text with the same vowels. For example:

hEllo’ and ‘pOle’ both contain exactly 1 e and exactly 1 o. The order of the vowels and the case from the original input word does not matter.

Imagine the following example:

hEllo    moose
pOle cccttt.ggg

We would end up with the following output:

:1

eo:2

eoo:1

The map code that I have so far is:

```
import sys
import re
 
line = sys.stdin.readline()
pattern = re.compile("[a,e,i,o,u]+")
while line:
  for char in pattern.findall(line):
    print(char+"\t"+"1")
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

and the reducer code:

```
import sys
 
current_word = None
current_count = 0
word = None
for line in sys.stdin:
  line = line.strip()
  word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
  count = int(count)
  if current_word == word:
    current_count += count
  else:
    if current_word:
      print('%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count))
    current_count = count
    current_word = word
if current_word == word:
  print('%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count))
```

When I run this MapReduce code in Hadoop I get the following output:

```
a 1
e 4
o 1
```

Comment: To clarify, what is the desired or expected output of the MapReduce code for this example? 
 Would it be `a 1
e 4
o 1` as is shown in the last part.

Comment: No the desired output would be the output for the code that you wrote. I’m stuck at the point where it only counts the vowels

Comment: The code that I wrote outputs a 1 e 4 o 1

Comment: 1) I suggest you use Pyspark instead 2) If code runs differently in Hadoop, you should show the commands you're using to execute it

Answer (score 0):

#### Standard version

Not sure if there's a way using regex (there probably is), but here's a non-regex approach that at least gets you the desired result. This approach could likely be improved upon, right now it's a sort of rough draft that seems to work for the case outlined in the original question. Let me know if I need to clarify anything in particular.

```py
from collections import defaultdict


def vowel_count_map(sentence: str):
    """
    Return a map of vowel sequence to frequency per word in sentence.
    """
    lowercased = sentence.lower()
    count = defaultdict(int)

    for word in lowercased.split(' '):
        vowel_seq = _count_vowels(word)
        count[vowel_seq] += 1

    return count


def _count_vowels(word, vowels='aeiou') -> str:
    """Return an alphabetized sequence of vowels found in word."""
    count = defaultdict(int)   # init counter

    for char in word:
        # Technically this `if` condition is not needed, and can be
        # omitted (not sure how it would affect performance?)
        if char in vowels:
            count[char] += 1
    
    # For example, this uses the same logic as below:
    #   'a' * 3 = 'aaa'
    return ''.join([vowel * count[vowel] for vowel in vowels])
```

#### Shorter version

Here's a one-liner version of the same function that I think is pretty cool, at the cost of being a little harder to understand:

```py
from collections import Counter

vowel_count_map = lambda sentence: Counter([''.join([v * word.count(v) for v in 'aeiou']) for word in sentence.lower().split(' ')])
```

#### Usage

I put together some sample strings we can use for test data, and pass as inputs to either version of the `vowel_count_map` function above. The first approach above returns a `defaultdict`, the second one returns a `Counter`. They are essentially both `dict`-like objects, so you can iterate over their key-value pairs as usual.

```py
a_string = "hEllo moose pOle cccttt.ggg"
b_string = "testuueaaxyzioabceezu actionable conciliatory"

print(vowel_count_map(a_string))
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'eo': 2, 'eoo': 1, '': 1})

print(vowel_count_map(b_string))
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'aaaeeeeiouuu': 1, 'aaeio': 1, 'aiioo': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to clarify, is the first function a mapper and the second a reducer?

Comment: I just edited the second one, but essentially both functions give the same output. In your example above they output a `dict`-like object of  `{'eo': 2, 'eoo': 1, '': 1}`. You might find it useful to iterate over the key-value pairs in that mapping.

Comment: I see, I think the problem with this is I can't use libraries since I am basically writing the code in python and then testing in Hadoop

Comment: These are all built in libraries, like `sys`. I'm not sure if it still poses a problem though.

Comment: Oh okay i'll try it out then thanks again!

Comment: No problem, let me know how it goes. If it helps you can use the second version which is shorter. Then you can call it like `vowel_count_map(string)` and iterate over the key-value pairs in the result.

Comment: It isn't running well in Hadoop but it works fine in Python. I am having trouble integrating the code you wrote into my original since I need a MapReduce code.

Comment: Yes, apologize about that. I am not really well versed in MapReduce or how it works. However if you understand the concepts behind how it done in Python, you should be able to implement the same in MapReduce. Let me know if you need clarification on any of the code.